# Closing a modal by clicking outside of the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have a modal window build with CSS. The modal can be closed by clicking outside of it.

My solution to open the modal works, closing the modal works too, when the event listeners are added to the page separately. However, they don't work together. When both the listeners are added to the page, the modal won't open.

How can I make them to work together?

**HTML**

```
<a href="#openModal" id="modal-window" class="event test">
  <div class="shorten-long-text test">
  </div>
</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog Dialog1">
  <div class="myModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body row">
      <div class="col-xs-6" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer uppercase color-main">
      <a href="#close" title="Close"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).click(function(ev) {
    if($(ev.target).attr('class') != ".Dialog1" ) {
        $(".Dialog1").removeClass('isOpen');
        $(".Dialog1").addClass('isClosed');
    }
});

$(".test").click(function() {
    $(".Dialog1").removeClass('isClosed');
    $(".Dialog1").addClass('isOpen');
});
```

Comment: Please define "it doesnt work together". If you need a modal to be in open state and closed state at the same time, I think you've to update your hardware.

Comment: it means, if i testing open or close seperat it works. if i have both in my code it doesn't work..

Comment: `ev.stopPropagation()` in `.test` clicker would prevent the event to bubble to `window`...

Comment: @Teemu got the solution. Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `toggleClass()`
html:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog isClosed Dialog1">
```

js:

```
$(window).click(function(ev) {
if(!$(ev.target).is('.Dialog1,.test')  $(".Dialog1").toggleClass('isClosed isOpen');
}                                       
});

$(".test").click(function() {
$(".Dialog1").toggleClass('isClosed isOpen');
});
```